# OpenID: transparent single-sign-on for multiple sites?

Tags: openid, single-sign-on

I'm considering OpenID as a common login system for multiple sites. When the user is already authenticated at one site, it would be preferable if they could be taken to the other sites without needing to redo their OpenID login for each one.

Does OpenID provide a mechanism like this for authorizing a group of domains at once with a single login?